# Why is my AngularJS ngModel binding to the time inputs, but not binding to the date inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, data-binding

I'm trying to bind an `input` of type `date` to a model. I'm able to bind to `time` fields, but I'm having trouble with `date` fields. The HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="HistoryCtrl">
    <input type="date" nm-model="startDate" />
    <input type="time" ng-model="startTime" />
    <input type="date" nm-model="endDate" />
    <input type="time" ng-model="endTime" />
    <button ng-click="updateForm()">Update</button>
</div>
```

This is my controller (simplified):

```
function HistoryCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.result = {
        result: 'success',
        start: '2013-11-23 03:00:00',
        end: '2013-11-24 16:30:00',
        delta: 0.05681799352169
    };

    $scope.updateForm = function () {
        $scope.updateTimespan($scope.result.start, $scope.result.end);
    };

    $scope.updateTimespan = function (start, end) {
        $scope.startDate = start.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.startTime = start.split(" ")[1];
        $scope.endDate = end.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.endTime = end.split(" ")[1];
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3m6r/2/

I'm using Google Chrome 31.0.1650.57 for Mac. When I click the "Update" button, the `time` fields update but the `date` fields do not. Why? Am I [doing it wrong](http://lemonodor.com/images/mccarthy-youre-doing-it-wrong-s.jpg)?

Comment: Perhaps because `nm-model` means nothing to angular.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using ng-model but type wrongs, "nm-model".

```
<input type="date" ng-model="startDate" />
<input type="time" ng-model="startTime" />
<input type="date" ng-model="endDate" />
<input type="time" ng-model="endTime" />
```

See [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t3m6r/3/)